# Cannot press UIButtons in a UIViewController when the controller is declared in the .m and not the .h

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

I have a UIViewController that contains subviews in the form of UIButtons.This controller is named "ControllerWithButtons" - In the first example everything works, but in the second example the buttons don't work. (It seems that their actions are not even being called) What is the difference?

**Example 1:** (Buttons work)

In the .h file:

```
@interface GlobalViewController : UIViewController

@property ControllerWithButtons *controllerWithButtons;

@end
```

In the .m file:

```
@implementation GlobalViewController

...

- (void)viewDidAppear {
   _controllerWithButtons = [ControllerWithButtons alloc] init];
   _controllerWithButtons.view.frame = self.view.frame;
   [self.view addSubview:_controllerWithButtons.view]
}

@end
```

---

**Example 2:** (Buttons don't work)

In the .h file:

```
@interface GlobalViewController : UIViewController

@end
```

In the .m file:

```
@implementation GlobalViewController

...

- (void)viewDidAppear {
   ControllerWithButtons *controllerWithButtons = [ControllerWithButtons alloc] init];
   controllerWithButtons.view.frame = self.view.frame;
   [self.view addSubview:controllerWithButtons.view]
}

@end
```

Comment: In example 2- I think `ControllerWithButtons` view is deallocating due to local reference .

Comment: @vp2698 This seems to be the correct answer. I learned something today! Thank you!